# In PlayN, how do I create a transparent CanvasImage?

Tags: playn

I wrote a simple example that I expected would do it. The relevant code is pasted below, complete source available [here](http://code.google.com/p/klenwell/source/browse/trunk/projects/java/playndev/playndev/core/src/main/java/com/googlecode/klenwell/playndev/core/).

First, the method of my game class that draws three circles as canvas images using the `asCanvasImage` method on my `Circle` class:

```
public void drawThreeTransparentCircles() {
    // create an immediate layer and add to root layer
    ImmediateLayer circleLayer = graphics().createImmediateLayer(
            new ImmediateLayer.Renderer() {
                public void render(Surface surf) {
                    Circle redCircle = new Circle(-25, 0, 50, Color.rgb(
                            255, 0, 0), 0.5f);
                    Circle whiteCircle = new Circle(0, 0, 50, Color.rgb(
                            255, 255, 255), 0.5f);
                    Circle blueCircle = new Circle(25, 0, 50, Color.rgb(0,
                            0, 255), 0.5f);
                    surf.drawImage(redCircle.asCanvasImage(),
                            redCircle.getScreenX(), redCircle.getScreenY());
                    surf.drawImage(whiteCircle.asCanvasImage(),
                            whiteCircle.getScreenX(),
                            whiteCircle.getScreenY());
                    surf.drawImage(blueCircle.asCanvasImage(),
                            blueCircle.getScreenX(),
                            blueCircle.getScreenY());
                }
            });

    rootLayer.add(circleLayer);
}
```

And then `asCanvasImage` method of my `Circle` class:

```
public CanvasImage asCanvasImage() {
    int diameter = radius * 2;
    CanvasImage circleImage = graphics().createImage(diameter, diameter);
    Canvas canvas = circleImage.canvas();
    canvas.setFillColor(color);
    canvas.fillCircle((float) radius, (float) radius, (float) radius);
    canvas.setAlpha(alpha);
    return circleImage;
}
```

The alpha value is set to 0.5 for each circle. But this is the result when I run the Java version:

[image]

**Edit:** I discovered that if I change the alpha value on the rootLayer, it makes the images transparent:

```
rootLayer.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

However I wish to make each of the circle images independently transparent with different alpha values. Does that mean I have to add each image to its own layer and set the transparency on that layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to create independent transparent circles using images layers. Is this the best way to accomplish this?

I added an `asImageLayer` method to my `Circle` class that creates a circle image using the `asCanvasImage` method above then creates an image layer from that and successfully applies the alpha value:

```
public ImageLayer asImageLayer() {
    CanvasImage image = asCanvasImage();
    ImageLayer imageLayer = graphics().createImageLayer(image);
    imageLayer.setAlpha(alpha);
    imageLayer.transform().translate(getScreenX(), getScreenY());
    return imageLayer;
}
```

My game class method that calls `asImageLayer` which in turn gets called by the `paint` method:

```
public void drawTransparentImageLayers() {
    GroupLayer groupLayer = graphics().createGroupLayer();
    groupLayer.add(bgLayer);
    groupLayer.add(redCircle.asImageLayer());
    groupLayer.add(whiteCircle.asImageLayer());
    groupLayer.add(blueCircle.asImageLayer());
    rootLayer.add(groupLayer);
}
```

The result (the circles moves slightly at random leaving a trace):

[image]

It works but the movement appears to slow down over time. Performance issue?

Comment: I figured out the performance issue was due to the rootLayer group accumulating layers. I solved it by simply clearing it. Or, in my case, limiting its size. See trimRootLayer method [here](http://code.google.com/p/klenwell/source/browse/trunk/projects/java/playndev/playndev/core/src/main/java/com/googlecode/klenwell/playndev/core/PlaynDev.java#100).